# Having issues with extracting the data from an API in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently doing a coding challenge for a job position and need to create a movie application that uses a simple REST API. They provided the endpoint and API key. I've managed to access the API and it's object but not sure how to display it. The only way I  was able to access the data was through a fetch method like this:

```
const URL = "https://url.example";
    fetch(URL, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Api-Key 12345abcd",
      }
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      setMovies(data);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

I'm able to see the object of data with my dev tools but i've tried everything to extract the specific data and display it but no luck.

Comment: Is the `movies` state correctly updating? How are you attempting to render said `movies` state? What is the issue? Is there an error? Can you update your question to include your [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for how you are processing and rendering the response?

Comment: Could you show us what data you get from the API endpoints?